# Regular expression for version number bigger than 1.18.10

Tags: python, regex

I need to verify if the version number of application bigger than 1.18.10.
How regular expression should look like in this case?

Comment: Are you sure regex is the best way to go about this?

Comment: to understand why you don't want to use a RE, you should read courses on [automata](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec03.pdf) and [Regular Expressions/NFA](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec04.pdf) to understand what RE really are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this. Use `split` and `tuple` comparison:

```
def is_recent(version):
    version_as_ints = (int(x) for x in version.split('.'))
    return tuple(version_as_ints) > (1, 18, 10)
```

And then check `is_recent("1.10.11")` or `is_recent("1.18.12")`

Comment: Appreciate the feedback Magnus

Answer (score 4):

Seems like this battery has already been included in Python in [`distutils.version`](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version) :

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
LooseVersion("1.18.11") > LooseVersion("1.18.10")
#True

LooseVersion("1.2.11") > LooseVersion("1.18.10")
#False (note that "2">"18" is True)

LooseVersion("1.18.10a") > LooseVersion("1.18.10")
#True
```

This takes into account splitting and comparing both version number parts as integers, and non-numeric parts (e.g alphabetic extension) seperately and correctly. (*If you want the alternate behaviour*, *(lexicographical comparison)*, you can directly compare the tuples of strings that result on a `version_num.split(".")`)

Note that there is also a `StrictVersion` variant that will throw an exception (`ValueError`) on alphabetic characters in the version string. See also [PEP386](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/) which is planning to deprecate both, replacing them with a `NormalizedVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expression for that, but something like:

```
major, minor, patch = v.split('.')
if int(major) > 1 or (int(major) == 1 and int(minor) >= 18):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why you need a regex, it's not a particularly good tool for doing complex range checking.

I would just `split` the string into a three-element array and then check each element, something like:

```
(p1, p2, p3) = verstr.split(".")

# May want to check they're numeric first.

if int(p1) < 1: return False
if int(p1) == 1:
    if int(p2) < 18: return False
    if int(p2) == 18:
        if int(p3) < 10: return False
return True
```