# Mongo Filter for version number bigger than 1.18.10

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to run a mongo query that only returns documents who's version field is bigger than '1.18.10'.

Related to: [Regular expression for version number bigger than 1.18.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040120/regular-expression-for-version-number-bigger-than-1-18-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a complex match like this, you'll need to use either the $regex or the $where operator: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/#evaluation.

The regex to use with $regex would be something like this:

```
^(([2-9]|[0-9]{2,}).*|1\.(([0-9]{3,}|[2-9][0-9]|19).*|18\.([0-9]{3,}|[2-9][0-9]|1[1-9])))
```

The core logic is this part:

```
[2-9]|[0-9]{2,}|(1\.<check_next_part_here>)
```

which is repeated a few times throughout but slightly tweaked. This matches anything bigger than 1:

- `[2-9]` (digits 2 to 9)
- `[0-9]{2,}` (two ore more digits: 10 onwards)

Or 1 and then moves on to check the next part:

- `1\.` (matches `1.`)